# How to search for a character in a string and output the index of every place that character appears? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, string, character, document, indexof

I figured it out, thank you. I need to move the body to the html. Changed some tags in the body section.

```
            }

            else
            {
                window.alert ("You entered an invalid character (" + enterLetter + ") please re-enter");
                secondPrompt();
            }

        }

</script>

<body onload = "firstPrompt();">

    <h2>
        Word Checker
    </h2>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) recursively:

```
function findMatches(str, char) {
    var i = 0,
        ret = [];
    while ((i = str.indexOf(char, i)) !== -1) {
        ret.push(i);
        i += char.length; //can use i++ too if char is always 1 character
    };
    return ret;
}
```

Usage in your code:

```
var matches = findMatches(enterWord, enterLetter);
if (!matches.length) { //no matches
    document.write ("String '" + enterWord + "' does not contain the letter '" + enterLetter + ".<br />");
} else {
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        document.write ("String '" + enterWord + "' contains the letter '" + enterLetter + "' at position " + matches[i] + ".<br />");
    }
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsbin.com/udevay/1)

[**Full source**](http://jsbin.com/udevay/1/edit) (with some tweaks from your last question)

Answer (score 2):

You can increment indexOf each time you find a match-

```
function indexFind(string, charac){
    var i= 0, found= [];
    while((i= string.indexOf(charac, i))!= -1) found.push(i++);
    return found;
}
```

**indexFind('It\'s more like it is today, than it ever was before','o');**

/*  returned value: (Array)
6,22,48
*/

Comment: Damn nice, you shortened my code 1 line further with the post-increment inside the push. +1. Even though, as OP is starting with JS, I wouldn't omit the optional braces.

Comment: Even shorter: `while(~(i= string.indexOf(charac, i)))`